# Glue crawler to read pattern matched s3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

While specifying `s3 path` in `AWS Glue Crawler`, can we mention some patterns to make the crawler read the files only with specific names in `s3 folder` instead of reading every file in the path?

Something like 
`s3://sample_folder/sample_file%pattern%.csv.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Glue doesn't support regex for inclusion filters. You can specify a folder path and set exclusion rules instead. For example, the path is `s3://sample_folder` and exclusion pattern `*.{txt,avro}` to filter out all txt and avro files.

See [Include and Exclude Patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write glue job and use `spark.read` method to use regex. Crawler doesn't have support for include-regex.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use Exclude pattern feature in a way to chose only the files that you want, like keep all the patterns you dont want in exclude patterns and then only the ones that you want will be considered.[Insert and Exclude pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude)

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information in the link provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.